# Gray out logging code using ReSharper

Tags: c#, .net, logging, resharper

Is it possible to use ReSharper to gray out useful but bloaty code using ReSharper? For example, when I want to add verbose logging it would be good to make the functional code stand out around the logging code.

I have tried using ReSharper's Pattern Catalog search to match patterns in my code and highlight them in gray but it only supports Hints, Suggestions, Warnings and Errors.

I'm looking for something similar to how `Debug.WriteLine` is displayed in Release mode, although I don't want to code to be compiled out.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. You could suggest it on their issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: It has been suggested here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437773

Answer (score 9):

You can sort-of achieve this, but it's kind of a hack. What you could do, is decorate your logging methods with the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx), using ReSharper's [External Annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html).

Annotations are used in ReSharper almost everywhere, it's how it knows to gray out the `Debug.WriteLine` line in Release, for example, since the `Debug.Write...` lines are decorated with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute.

What you could do is *cheat* by making ReSharper *think* that such a conditional method exists on your logger's methods. You can do it by applying this attribute externally via XML.

I wrote about doing something like this in [my blog](http://hmemcpy.com/2013/03/even-more-resharper-annotations-hackery-marking-3rd-party-code-as-obsolete/), here's how you could do this:

1. Create a file called **YourLogger.ExternalAnnotations.xml**, e.g. NLog.ExternalAnnotations.xml and place it next to your logger assembly.
2. Add the following:

> ```
> <assembly name="NLog">
>   <member name="M:NLog.Logger.Info(System.String)">
>     <attribute ctor="M:System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
>       <argument>LOG</argument>
>     </attribute>
>   </member>
>   <member name="M:NLog.Logger.Debug(System.String)">
>     <attribute ctor="M:System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
>       <argument>LOG</argument>
>     </attribute>
>   </member>
> </assembly>
> ```

For each method you wish to "gray out", you will need to add a `<member>` block with the XML-Doc ID name of the method. In ReSharper 8 EAP there's an option **Copy XML-Doc ID to Clipboard**, located under ReSharper's **Edit** menu.

This essentially causes ReSharper's engine to think there's a `[Conditional("LOG")]` defined in the logger's type metadata.

After you've added all the desired methods, simply reload the solution. You should get what you are looking for (sort of... like I said, it's a hack :))

[image: ReSharper hackery]

Comment: I highly not recommending doing this, because invocations erased by `[Conditional]` attribute affect C# compiler control flow graph and definite assignment analysis, as well as R#'s code analysis. ReSharper will ignore any useful information about expressions being evaluated as part of `[Conditional]` invocations, that's "too much" for just graying ot the code. Better write a plugin :)

Comment: @ControlFlow I should probably add "don't try this at home" disclaimer :)

Answer (score -3):

Just don't do it.

It's a bad way to cope with unstructured code, and it will only be slightly helpful, and only to you. If you do it the way you suggest (if possible), other developers must install ReSharper and configure it like you if they want the business logic to stand out.

This isn't what you asked, but I think a better approach is to move the verbose logging into separate methods/classes. Then logging-related code would only be a single method call in your current methods.

Comment: You can't move all mundane code (such as logging or checking) to separate methods, it's usually interlaced with logic hard.